# Postgres JOIN on timestamp fails

Tags: postgresql

Trying to do a simple `FULL OUTER JOIN` on a timestamp and it is outputing the full cartesian product instead of matching identical dates. What is wrong here?

[SQL Fiddle with example data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/afb9a/1)

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    id INT,
    time TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE B (
     id INT,
     time TIMESTAMP
);
```

Query:

```
SELECT A.Id AS a_id, A.Time AS a_time, B.Id AS b_id, B.Time AS b_time 
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.Time = B.Time

-- This works:
-- SELECT A.id, A.time, B.id, B.time
-- FROM A
-- FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
```

Comment: What result you expect?

Comment: The same thing as the commented out query.

Comment: A full outer join produces a cartesian product by definition. Maybe you mean inner join?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong [**parameters**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) on `TO_DATE()` on your `INSERTS` easy to test if you do

```
SELECT * FROM A; 
SELECT * FROM B;
```

Instead of

```
 TO_DATE('01-01-2002', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Should be:

```
 TO_DATE('01-01-2002', '%DD-%MM-%Y')
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cbf0f/1)**

Answer (score 1):

In your sql fiddle all your inserted dates are the same because your date pattern is wrong. Try using  TO_DATE('01-01-2002', 'DD-MM-YYYY') instead of TO_DATE('01-01-2002', '%d-%m-%y')